# Error in funtrans(sort(unique(model_frame[[y]]))) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r, lme4

First of all - are there any good references to help me get better at interpreting error messages? My current tactic is to first check the script, then check the data, then surf google for hours/post a question here.

I have a model (below) and I am trying to use `ggpredict` to fit a curve that shows the relationship between winter fires and time.

```
data <- read.csv('StacksOverflow.csv')
dput(head(data))
```

Data:

```
structure(list(X = 1:6, yrblock15 = c(2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L), circleID = 1:6, time = c(5.270172597, 4.270172617, 
3.348596103, 3.019112219, 2.905252281, 2.773856447), ThreeYearRain = c(748.9863518, 
744.4805429, 748.6081666, 747.5941999, 746.3382951, 740.9514718
), summer = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), winter = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 4L), total = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 7L), claylake = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0), spinsandplain = c(99.53, 90.39, 50.7, 63.8, 
73.65, 82.73), rain15 = c(412.5357625, 412.1096373, 414.7593319, 
416.1126083, 416.1484008, 413.5668281), coefrain15 = c(48.03688416, 
48.05843172, 47.98508211, 48.13217304, 48.39476675, 48.51635011
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Packages:

```
library(lme4)
library(ggeffects)
```

Model:

```
m3 <- lmer(winter~scale(log(time))+scale(spinsandplain)+scale(rain15)+
           scale(claylake)+scale(rain15)*scale(log(time))+(1|circleID),
           na.action=na.fail, data=data, REML=FALSE)

d <- ggeffect(m3, terms = "time[exp]")
```

Which produces this error:

> Error in funtrans(sort(unique(model_frame[[y]]))) : 
>     non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Any suggestions why this is occurring??

Comment: Thank you. Once I do that, how do I get it into stack overflow though?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the packages that you have used through `library()`.

Comment: No worries, I have added the packages that I am using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to your existing error-message-fu (Googling and posting on forums), the only other suggestion I have is that *sometimes* you can try to find the relevant code in the source code, e.g. if you search for the error message on the `ggeffects` Github repo you can get [here](https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/search?q=funtrans%28sort%28unique%28model_frame%5B%5By%5D%5D%29%29%29&unscoped_q=funtrans%28sort%28unique%28model_frame%5B%5By%5D%5D%29%29%29). This may or may not help, though. (The way I diagnosed your problem was more basic; I started from a model with just `log(time)` (or the equivalent), saw that it worked, then tried a model with `scale(log(time))` and saw that it didn't ...)

---

---

I can reproduce this if I use `scale(log(x))`

```
library(lme4)
library(ggeffects)
sleepstudy$Days1 <- 1 + sleepstudy$Days
```

This is fine:

```
fm <- lmer(Reaction ~ log(Days1) + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)
ggeffect(fm, term = "Days1 [exp]")
```

However,

```
fm <- lmer(Reaction ~ scale(log(Days1)) + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)
ggeffect(fm, term = "Days1 [exp]")
```

> Error in funtrans(sort(unique(model_frame[[y]]))) :  non-numeric argument to mathematical function

It looks like `scale(log(.))` is generally problematic. `ggeffect(fm)` gives an error too (albeit a slightly different one).  If we use `scale(Days)`, or `log(Days1)`, we're OK, but `scale(log(Days))` doesn't work.

The workaround would be to define your own variable, e.g. `sleepstudy$sl_Days1 <- scale(log(sleepstudy$Days+1))`, and go from there (i.e. `lmer(...); ggeffect(fm, terms="sl_Days1 [exp]")`.

You could try posting an issue/feature request on the [issues list for ggeffects](https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/issues) (first for a more useful error message, and secondarily for something that would make this work more seamlessly)

Comment: having looked at the code I could give you a more specific diagnosis of what's going wrong, if that would help ...

Comment: Hello Ben, I am just attempting to apply your above suggestion to see if I can work it out - but definitely wouldn't say no to a more specific diagnosis. Thank you!

Comment: I have checked it off, I hope one day to have an ounce of the R wisdom that you have!

Answer (score 2):

This is meant as a comment, not as an answer (Ben already answered your question, here's just some additional information that is too long for a comment...).

*ggeffects* uses the [insight-package](http://easystats.github.io/insight/) to access model information, like - in this particular example - model frames. To easily match column names from the model frame with variable names provided in the `terms`-argument in `ggpredict()` or `ggeffect()`, column names are "cleaned" using `insight::clean_names()`. However, nested commands like `scale()` in combination with `log()` are an edge-case that leads to your reported error.

In your case, the code `model_frame[[y]]` looks for `Days1` (i.e. `y` has the value `"Days1"` in your case), however, the column name is transformed ("cleaned") to `"log"` instead of `"Days1"`, so `ggpredict()` tries to access `model_frame[["Days1"]]`, although the column is named `"log"`.

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(insight)
sleepstudy$Days1 <- 1 + sleepstudy$Days
fm <- lmer(Reaction ~ scale(log(Days1)) + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)

colnames(model.frame(fm))
#> [1] "Reaction"          "scale(log(Days1))" "Subject"

clean_names(colnames(model.frame(fm)))
#> [1] "Reaction" "log"      "Subject"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I must check how I can solve this issue.